# Problem using Parseval's theorem for solving an integral

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, fourier-transform, parsevals-identity

> I need to use Parseval's theorem to calculate the following integral:
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left |\frac{1-e^{-iwt}}{iw}  \right |^{2}dt$$

I thought to find the transform of $$f(t) = \frac{1-e^{-iwt}}{iw}$$ and then use Parseval.

I have problems finding the Fourier transform of f(t) using properties by knowing common transforms.

The definition used for the Fourier transform is: 
$$\hat{f}(w) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-iwt}\cdot  dt$$

Comment: It might be useful to note that $f(t) = \frac{1-e^{-iwt}}{iw} = \int_0^t e^{-iwu} \, du$, so $f'(t) = e^{-iwu}$.

Comment: Be careful, the $w$ in $f(t)$ is not the same $w$ in $\hat f(w).$

Comment: Thank you! Shouldn't it be the integral of the exponential multiplied by the Heavyside function from -oo to t? If that's correct then I should find f(w)/(iw) to calculate the integral by Parseval right?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but the integrand is positive and periodic and integrating a positive, periodic function over all $\mathbb{R}$ usually diverges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: I think the denominator should be $wt$ instead of $w$ as the integral would evaluate to $\infty$ otherwise. Also,
$$\frac{1-e^{-iwt}}{iwt} = e^{-iwt/2}\frac{e^{iwt/2}-e^{-iwt/2}}{iwt} = e^{-iwt/2}\frac{\sin(wt/2)}{wt/2}.$$
Consequently,
$$\left|\frac{1-e^{-iwt}}{iwt}\right| = \left|\frac{\sin(wt/2)}{wt/2}\right|.$$

Comment: Yes that should be great but it's not iwt, its iw.

Comment: @Verónica In that case, as I also mentioned in the answer, the integral would evaluate to $\infty$ as $\sin^2(\theta) = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}-0.5\cos(2\theta)$.